# How do you open an application that you made in a new text document

Tags: 13.10

I just made an application with text editor 13.10 but i cannot figure out how to run it please help I Tried opening it in chrome but all it did was show the text

Comment: what kind of application , you mean a script ?

Comment: just run it through terminal by `bash /path/filename.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on the type of file. If you wrote the program as a script (.sh, .txt, .py, etc) then you just need to right click it, click properties, select the permissions tab, and make it executable. Then double clicking it will give you the option to edit it or run it, optionally in a terminal. This dialog can be disabled in your file manager's settings.

If you wrote code in a compiled language (C, C++, Java, etc) you will need to compile it using commands like `make`. There are many excellent tutorials for compiling programs in Linux (Ubuntu is a distro of Linux) that you can find by searching for `how to compile C++ in Linux` in the search engine of your choice, substituting C++ for the language you are using.